# 2 number multiplying and adding

Tags: linux, shell-script

```
M="Wrong"  
P="Wrong"  
I=$1  
while [ "$I" != "" ]  
do  
  case $I in  
  -m | --multiplying)   
      shift  
      M=`expr $1 \* $2`  
      ;;  
  -p | --plus )   
      shift  
      P=`expr $1 + $2`  
      ;;   
  *)  echo "Something wrong"  
      exit 1  
      ;;  
  esac  
  shift  
  I=$1  
done  
echo "Multiplying=$M, Adding=$P"
```

I give two number after each -m and -p
So when i run my code i want this to happen

```
./code.sh -m 2 2 -p 5 5  

Multiplying=4 Adding=10
```

my code simply skip the and -p part and goes straigh to

```
*) echo "Something wrong"
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: (1) Thank you for describing the behavior you want.  But, when you ask a "What am I doing wrong?" question, you should also describe the behavior that you are getting.  (2) Add ``set -x`` to your script to see what is happening.

Comment: my code simply skip the and -p part and goes straigh to *) echo "Something wrong"

Comment: and doesnt display any result

Comment: (1) Thank you.  I forgot to say, "Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete."  (2) The ```set -x``` should illuminate what's happening.

Comment: @KhushrajRathod Why? This is the correct site for it.

Comment: @KhushrajRathod not at all! If anything, it is better here. This is a question about shell scripting which is a very large part of what this site is about. Please take the time to familiarize yourself with the scopes of the relevant sites before suggesting migrations.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh

M="Wrong"
P="Wrong"

while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do

    case $1 in
        -m|--multiplying)
            M=$(( $2 * $3 ))
            ;;
        -p|--plus)
            P=$(( $2 + $3 ))
            ;;
        *)  echo 'Error in command line options' >&2
            exit 1
    esac

    shift 3
done

printf 'Multiplying=%s, Adding=%s\n' "$M" "$P"
```

Your code is a bit difficult to follow due to the `shift`s being spread out, but the main issue is that you are lacking one `shift` operation per loop.  Your script calculates the result of the first arithmetic operation correctly, but when it comes to looking at the second arithmetic operation, it has only performed two shift operations (each `-p A B` requires three `shift` to be processed and for the following `-m C D` to be in `$1`, `$2` and `$3`).

My modified version of your code only does a single `shift 3` after each operation, while the operation itself uses `$1`, `$2` and `$3`.  I'm also using the more modern arithmetic expansion `$(( ... ))` rather than the antiquated `expr` utility.  I'm testing on `$#` whether there are more command line arguments to process and I've update the output slightly so that `printf` is used for variable data and so that diagnostic messages are outputted onto the standard error stream.

Also note that having options that take more than one option argument is a bit unusual.